# Issue with NuGet Package Manager

Tags: nuget

I have a project that I recently converted over to use Entity Framework. I installed the package on my development machine and everything worked perfectly and I continued to re-vamp the project.

I recently pushed out the first update to my production server with the Entity Framework code in it. When I tried to build the solution it threw all kinds of errors, namely this one over and over:

```
 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. bamblack.viewmodel
```

I went into my NuGet Package Manager, and it says EntityFramework was installed. I then tried to install it through the Package Manager Console, said the same thing. So I then tried to uninstall it. It says it can't locate the package!

I'm sure it's because I didn't do the actual install on the production machine and it's just missing a DLL somewhere, but I'm not sure where. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I tried manually adding a Reference to the System.Data.Entity.dll and System.Data.Entity.Design.dll files, it errored out saying "This project already has a reference to System.Data.Entity." When I went through each of my projects in the solutions, found the "EntityFramework" entry (which had a yellow triangle on it) and removed it manually, it still says the same thing when I try to manually add it or do it through NuGet or the Package Manager Console.

Comment: No, it was an issue with pushing the project out to my server and it losing the references that it should contain to certain DLL's (which are imported with the project). It directly relates to Visual Studio, so it really isn't off-topic as you say it is. If you want to close it at least get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that all I needed to do was un/reinstall the references to EF on my development machine and push it out again. Strange that it didn't push them out the first time. Issue was resolved.